# Is there lore behind the difference between the brown and green orcs of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, warcraft

Why are there brown orcs such as Warchief Garrosh Hellscream? Why are there only a few of them scattered throughout [World of] Warcraft's Azeroth and Outland?

Comment: there is lore behind that. the orcs were naturally brown (as seen in Outlands) but turned green when they were tainted and brought to Azeroth. if i had more time i'd find some references and post as an actual answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[From Wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Orcs#Skin_color):

> #### Skin color
>
> All original orcs were brown-skinned;
> from bark-like brown to reddish-brown.
> However, their bodies react when
> exposed to warlock magic; though the
> nature of this change is somewhat
> different in other fel-touched races.
> The nature of orcish fel magic means
> that all nearby orcs, including those
> who avoid warlock magic, take on a
> green pigmentation and gain body mass
> (though why the Mag'har are much
> bigger than Durotar orcs in World of
> Warcraft is unknown). This color
> change appears to be genetic as
> Thrall, who had little direct exposure
> to warlock magic until recently, has
> had green skin from birth.
>
> As this corruption progresses, the
> orc's eyes may become flaming orbs of
> red or green and their skin will soon
> change from green to scarlet,
> transforming them into fel orcs.
> Through certain rituals, this state is
> reversible. However, should the orc
> continue to drink large amounts of
> demonic blood, they enter the final
> irreversible stage of transformation
> and mutate horrifically; growing
> additional fangs and erupting with
> horns from their backs, arms and
> hands.
>
> Currently, orcs of the Horde have a
> wide variety of "natural" pigments,
> ranging between shades of light green,
> dark drab olive, brown to grayish
> brown.