# How did Garrosh Hellscream become the new Warchief?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, warcraft

How did Garrosh Hellscream become the new Warchief? What happen to Thrall? Was this explain somewhere other than a novel, such as quest with World of Warcraft?

*This is follow up question to: [Is there lore behind the difference between the brown and green orcs of Warcraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13031/is-there-lore-behind-the-difference-between-the-brown-and-green-orcs-of-warcraft)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short version: It's all explained in [The Shattering,](http://www.wowpedia.org/The_Shattering:_Prelude_to_Cataclysm) a novel released recently in the leadup to Cataclysms release. WoWinsider did those of us not inclined to read the Warcraft novels a favor by providing by-character synopses of the novel. [Here's the rundown on Thralls story and why he abdicated](http://wow.joystiq.com/2010/10/18/the-shattering-plot-summary-thrall/), and [Here's the meat on Garrosh's early days as Thralls chosen successor,](http://wow.joystiq.com/2010/10/19/the-shattering-plot-summary-garrosh-and-cairne/) and the somewhat rocky first few months as Warchief.

The Really Short Version: Thrall left Azeroth on a pilgrimage to Draenor when the Cataclysm was approaching to investigate stirrings among the elementals - Garrosh, as his second, was named 'Acting Warchief' in Thralls absence. In the aftermath of Deathwings return, Thrall has applied his efforts primarily to working with the Earthen Ring and the Council of Tirsifal to eliminate the threats of the Twilights Hammer, Deathwing, and hordes of extremely angry Elementals after the Cataclysm. Meanwhile, in the wake of the Razing of Ogrimmnar and the elemental invasion, Garrosh, already a war hero from the campaign in Northrend, has become *even more* popular with the Orcs of the Horde, as well as the Tauren, now led by Baine Bloodhoof, cementing his power.

Comment: Unfortunately, Vol'jin (leader of the Trolls) and Sylvanus (leader of the Forsaken) both hate Garrosh.  This becomes clear if you play the Troll starting area and Silverpine Forest areas respectively.

Comment: Yes, but ultimately, in the politics of the Horde, the Forsaken have been marginalized since the Wrathgate incident (this is largely *why* they hate him in fact), and while the Trolls aren't too fond of Garrosh, they *are* still loyal to the idea of the Horde, and Garrosh has tried to make inroads to mend that fence.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating a new Troll character post-shattering?

> **Vision of Garrosh Hellscream says:**
>   Don't talk back to me, troll. You know
>   who was left in charge here. Haven't
>   you stopped to ask yourself why Thrall
>   chose me instead of you?
>
> **Vision of Vol'jin says:** Dere be no question why, Garrosh. He gave ya tha
>   title because ya be Grom's Son and
>   because tha people be wantin' a war
>   hero.

As mentioned, Thrall has chosen to leave the Horde to attend to "more important" matters, namely mending the world post-shattering, along with The Earthen Ring, Malfurion Stormrage, and other lore "heavy hitters".

Answer (score 1):

**In Short-**
Garrosh was left by Thrall as acting war chief while thrall was working with other shamans in the Earthen Ring during the Cataclysm. Thrall also left Cairne Bloodhoof with Garrosh to advise him. Not too long after Thrall left, Garrosh dueled Cairne for the rite to acting warchief as they both knew that Thrall's reign was at an end. Cairne lost the duel after Garrosh's axe was poisoned by Magatha Grimtotem. This sparked a Tauren Civil War between the Bloodhoof, led by Cairne's son Baine, and the Grimtotems, Led by Magatha. The Bloodhoofs defeated the Grimtotems and earned the right to thunder bluff.  After Deathwing was defeated, Thrall was announced as leader of the Earthen Ring and could not be both Warchief of the horde and Leader of the Earthen Ring at the same time. Thrall chose to lead the Earthen Ring and left Garrosh to be Warchief.